# Check array key parameters and call method with appropriate amount of parameters

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I've got a class with methods that take a different amount of parameters. And I got an array with methods, also with different amount of parameters.

I need to call the methods with the proper amount of parameters for it to work. If the key  in the array has no value, there should always be `$input` passed through as the first parameter.

Anybody who knows what I'm doing wrong or need to do to achieve it?

```
$arr = ['trim', 'between' => [6, 254]];
```

**My failed attempt**

```
foreach ($arr as $method) {
    if (count($method) === 0) {
        $this->$method($input);
    } elseif (count($method) === 1) {
        $this->$method($input, $method[0]);
    } elseif (count($method) === 2) {
        $this->$method($input, $method[0], $method[1]);
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
Fatal error: Method name must be a string in (..) on line N
```

**Methods**

```
private function trim($input) //1 param
{
    $this->input = trim($input);
}

private function max($input, $max) //2 params
{
    if (!(strlen($input) <= $max)) {
        $this->errors[] = __FUNCTION__;
    }
}

private function between($input, $min, $max) //3 param
{
    if (!(strlen($input) > $min && strlen($this->input) < $max)) {
        $this->errors[] = __FUNCTION__;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I suggest modify the method using last param as array, so you move the check inside the method: `beteweeen($input,$param_array(){}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily call whatever method you want dynamically with a variable number of arguments with [`call_user_func_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). There's just some details to take care of.

First, the format of `$arr` is convenient but it's not consistent. Sometimes the method name is the value (e.g. `trim`), sometimes it's the key (e.g. `between`). You need to normalize things:

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if (is_int($key)) {   // $key => 'trim'
        $method = $value;
        $arguments = [$input];
    }
    else {                // 'trim' => [...]
        $method = $key;
        $arguments = array_merge([$input], is_array($value) ? $value : [$value]);
    }
```

Now that you have `$method` and `$arguments` neat and tidy, the final step is trivial:

```
    call_user_func_array([$this, $method], $arguments);
```

Comment: So would I have to reformat my array? Like so `$arr = [0 => 'trim', 'between' => [6, 254]];`? Also, I'm getting a bunch of warnings: `Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array` and `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`.

Comment: @502Error: Your array is already formatted like that, you can see it with `var_dump($arr)`. The warnings are presumably caused by single-parameter definitions such as `'larger' => 42` that I overlooked because there was none in the example. I edited the answer and it should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

to understand an error
$arr = [0 => 'trim', 'between' => [6, 254]];

you iterate values so in $method you got 1) 'trim', 2) [6,254] (not 'between')